# SQL CASE wrong output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have this weird encounter using CASE in sql 2014.

This is my query:

```
  SELECT (CASE WHEN dbo.GetFunctionAge(C.Birthdate) = 0 
               THEN '' ELSE dbo.GetFunctionAge(C.Birthdate)
          END) AS Age
         ,dbo.GetFunctionAge(C.Birthdate)
         ,c.Birthdate
 FROM Client C
 WHERE ClientID = '34d0d845-e3a6-4078-8936-953ff3378eac'
```

this is the output:

[image]

Here is the GetFunctionAge function if you might ask.

```
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM dbo.sysobjects 
  WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[GetFunctionAge]') AND 
        xtype in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF'))
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFunctionAge]

GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFunctionAge](@BirthDate DATETIME)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Age INT

IF(@BirthDate = '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000')
BEGIN
    SET @Age = 0
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Age = DATEDIFF(hour,@BirthDate,GETDATE())/8766
END

RETURN @Age
END
GO
```

**Question:**
Why is Column Age in my output is `0`which should be `''`?
I added `(No column name)` to show that its output is `0` so my expected output base from my case condition is `''` not `0`
I didn't receive any error regarding inconsistency of data so why is case behaving like that?

Thanks for those who could clarify this to me.

Comment: Why '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000'? Use NULL instead.

Comment: What happens if you replace the `''` with `-1`?

Comment: You are returning an Int value from dbo.GetFunctionAge(C.Birthdate) which is @Age. Therefore, when you use it in your case statement it returns an int value as well. ' ' becomes 0.

Comment: please try '0' while you are checking in case, may be it is not comparing correctly.

Comment: 1) 2014 has a plain `DATE` type.  2) Why not `DATEDIFF(year, @BirthDate, GETDATE())`, instead of using hours?  2b) The hours value is wrong - there's 8760 hours in a (365-day) year.  You'd potentially have problems with DST anyways...

Comment: @jarlh - that's the way we save min date time when the user doesn't pick a date for birthday. I don't do the database design so I can't argue much with it.

Comment: @TT its output is -1

Comment: @NituBansal i tried no success. The output is still the same. But I think you are right sql might be confuse comparing it.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse thanks for the advice. I know we have to do some enhancement on age conversion. I'll try your advices.

Comment: @Kim Yes it is returning 0 but using CASE condition i set it to '' when the output is 0 but its returning 0 instead which is weird. But I get your point maybe the CASE was confuse of the type and return int instead. thanks for the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `cast` it into `varchar` so you can return `' '`.

```
 SELECT (CASE WHEN dbo.GetFunctionAge(C.Birthdate) = 0 
               THEN '' ELSE Cast(dbo.GetFunctionAge(C.Birthdate) as varchar(5))
          END) AS Age
         ,dbo.GetFunctionAge(C.Birthdate)
         ,c.Birthdate
 FROM Client C
 WHERE ClientID = '34d0d845-e3a6-4078-8936-953ff3378eac'
```

But If you wish to remain your `Age column` in data type `int`.

You could just use `NULL` instead of `' '`

Comment: I'll give this answer the credit as its the simplest, shortest working solution. Casting is the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
      (CASE
            WHEN a.ageint = 0 THEN ''
            ELSE cast(a.ageint as varchar(3))
      END) AS Age
    , a.ageint
    , c.Birthdate
FROM Client as C
      CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT
                  ISNULL(dbo.GetFunctionAge(C.Birthdate), 0) AS ageint
      ) AS a
WHERE ClientID = '34d0d845-e3a6-4078-8936-953ff3378eac'
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer its working. So Casting is the solution to my problem. But its a bit long compare to the other one. I think the cross apply doesn't need anymore as GetFunctionAge function will never return a null value. But its a good practice to always check with null thank's for it

Comment: yes, casting to a string is needed because you use `' '` in that column. The purpose of the `cross apply` is to avoid repeated calls to that function. Use of `isnull` or `coalesce` is optional but if there is any possibility of NULL as a returned result then you may need to use an `outer apply`. By the way: "length of sql" is not a good measure of quality, short isn't always good (or vice versa).

Comment: oh yes i haven't notice it. you use it to avoid repeated calls. is it a good practice to do such thing? sorry im not that familiar yet with cross apply. is it faster than the other answer? when returning result?

Comment: Yes it can be faster and yes it can be regarded as good practice for function calls, but you do not have to do it this way. You could use a derived table approach instead.